# How to create a mysql loop of multiple table names structure and data copy to second database

Tags: mysql, database, arrays, foreach, multiple-tables

**What I'm trying to accomplish.**
My site is live, and I'm making some changes to it.
When I'm ready to go live with the changes, I will essentially drop the old database (myFirstDb) and put the new one up(mySecondDb).
BUT - I will want to keep a few of the tables from the live site(myFirstDb) - and bring them into the new database (mySecondDb).
I know I can do this via phpMyAdmin - but that only allows one table at a time to be copied.

**MY QUESTION:**
What kind of SQL Query in mySQL will allow me to define the tables to move from database one to database two. (Keeping the structure and data etc)

**So here's what I have so far.**

First off, is it possible to create a loop in mySql - SQL query? If so...

Could someone assist me proper syntax for creating an array in mySQL?

**How would I go about creating the array in valid sql syntax?**

> // define array of table names here. <-- how to form this?
>
> SET @table_name_array = ('tableFive', 'tableSeven', 'tableNine', 'tableFifteen', 'tableNineteen', 'tableNth', 'tableMaybeOneMore');

**How would I go about looping thru that array in proper sql syntax?**

> // start loop thru each table name <-- how to write this?

My code so far

```
SET @database_name := 'myFirstDb';
SET @second_database_name := 'mySecondDb';

// define array of table names here. <-- how to form this?
SET @table_name_array = ('tableFive', 'tableSeven', 'tableNine', 'tableFifteen', 'tableNineteen', 'tableNth', 'tableMaybeOneMore');

// start loop thru each table name <-- how to write this?

SET @table_name := 'value';
SET @second_db_table_name := @table_name;

CREATE TABLE @second_db_table_name LIKE @table_name
ALTER TABLE @second_db_table_name DISABLE KEYS
INSERT INTO @second_db_table_name SELECT * FROM @table_name
ALTER TABLE @table_name ENABLE KEYS

//end loop here
```

Comment: You could use mysqldump for this and save a ton of headaches.

Comment: mysqldump and re-create will avoid the locking of your first table as well

Comment: mysqldump is done via shell command right?

Comment: how would I go about this via mysqldump - - with an array of table names? or could I just do it with a comma separated list of database.table1Name, database.table2Name et al.?